# pytorch: can't load CNN model and do prediction TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I trained a CNN model using MNIST dataset and now want to predict a classification of the image, which contains a number 3.

But when I tried to use this CNN to predict, pytorch gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

And here's what I write:

```
cnn = torch.load("/usr/prakt/w153/Desktop/score_detector.pkl")
img = scipy.ndimage.imread("/usr/prakt/w153/Desktop/resize_num_three.png")
test_x = Variable(torch.unsqueeze(torch.FloatTensor(img), dim=1), volatile=True).type(torch.FloatTensor).cuda()
test_output, last_layer = cnn(test_x)
pred = torch.max(test_output, 1)[1].cuda().data.squeeze()
print(pred)
```

here's some explaination:
`img` is the to be predicted image with size 28*28 `score_detector.pkl` is the trained CNN model

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem where I'm getting `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` and I'm not even trying to use the GPU.

Answer (score 13):

Indeed, you are loading a state_dict rather than the model itself.

Saving the model is as follows:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_state.pth')
```

Whereas to load the model state you first need to init the model and then load the state

```
model = Model()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_state.pth'))
```

If you trained your model on GPU but would like to load the model on a laptop which doesn't have CUDA, then you would need to add one more argument

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_state.pth', map_location='cpu'))
```

Comment: May I ask, how to define `Model()` in your second method?

Comment: @ahbon have a look at this [MNIST example](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py)

The ``Net`` class is where the model is defined and then initialized in the line 105 as follows

`model = Net().to(device)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `score_detector.pkl` is actually a state_dict and not the model itself. You will need to instantiate the model first and then load the state_dict, so your first line should be replaced by something like this:

```
cnn = MyModel()
cnn.load_state_dict("/usr/prakt/w153/Desktop/score_detector.pkl")
```

and then the rest should work.
See [this link](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/serialization.html#recommend-saving-models) for more information.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you saved a model that was on a GPU, make sure your current model is on the GPU with "myModel.to(device)" or equivalent before loading the state.