# Converting PyTorch to CoreML gives a TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I've been following Apple's [coremltools docs](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/pytorch-conversion-examples) for converting PyTorch segmentation models to CoreML.

While it works fine when we're loading a remote PyTorch model, I'm yet to figure out a working Python script to perform conversions with local/already-downloaded PyTorch models.

The following piece of code throws a `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

```
#This works fine: model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.6.0', 'deeplabv3_resnet101',pretrained=True).eval()
model = torch.load('local_model_file.pth')
input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)
input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_batch)['out'][0] #error here
torch_predictions = output.argmax(0)
```

There is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342167/3849039) that offers a solution by initialising the model class and loading the state_dict, but I wonder what's the concrete solution when we don't have access to the PyTorch model?

Comment: What is in `local_model_file.pth`? Is it the state dict of a model? That is, is it created by `torch.save(some_local_model.state_dict(), 'local_model_file.pth')`?

Comment: @kmkurn It's a Pytorch model file I downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: I understand that. From the error, `model` is a dict, so I suspect it's the state dict of some model. Can you post the output of `repr(model)` to confirm?

Comment: Yes it's an OrderedDict. The output is too long. It starts with `OrderedDict([('module.stage1.rebnconvin.conv_s1.weight', tensor([[[[ 3.7425e-01, -2.8370e-02,  3.3517e-01],
          [ 4.2106e-01,  9.9034e-02,  1.9682e-01],
          [ 4.6511e-01,  2.7230e-01,  6.5343e-02]],`

Comment: I had downloaded the model from here and loaded it in my converter script: https://github.com/levindabhi/cloth-segmentation

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `model` is a state dict, which is a dictionary from parameter names to the parameter tensor values. As [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342167/3849039) stated, the right way to load a state dict is by (a) creating the model object that the state dict belongs to and then (b) use `nn.Module.load_state_dict` to load the state dict. To do (a), you need access to the model's class definition. If you don't have that access, then unfortunately I don't see any reliable way to load the state dict.

You *might* be able to guess what the class' `__init__` look like by looking at the parameter names in the state dict (e.g., `'module.stage1.rebnconvin.conv_s1.weight'` looks like a convolution). However, even if the guess is correct and the state dict can be loaded, you still need to define the `forward` method because the state dict only stores the parameters.